# R - Merge two elements of a list in an iterative pdf task

Tags: r, dictionary, pdf, tidyverse, purrr

For a pdf mining task in R, I need your help.

I wish to mine 1061 multi-page pdf files with the file names `pdf_filenames`, for which I would like to extract the content of the first two pages of each pdf file.

So far, I have managed to get the content of all pdf files using the `map` function from the `purrr` library and `pdf_text` function from `pdftools` library.

```
> pdfs = pdf_filenames %>% 
        map(pdf_text)
```

This outputs a list with each element of the list representing one pdf file. The structure of the `pdfs` list is:

```
> str(pdfs)
List of 1061
 $ : chr [1:3] "Content page 1_pdf1" "Content page 2_pdf1" "Content page 3_pdf1"
 $ : chr [1:4] "Content page 1_pdf2" "Content page 2_pdf2" "Content page 3_pdf2" "Content page 4_pdf2"
 $ : chr [1:2] "Content page 1_pdf3" "Content page 2_pdf3"
 .
 .
 .
```

My desired output is:

```
List of 1061
 $ : chr [1:2] "Content page 1_pdf1 Content page 2_pdf1" "Content page 3_pdf1"
 $ : chr [1:3] "Content page 1_pdf2 Content page 2_pdf2" "Content page 3_pdf2" "Content page 4_pdf2"
 $ : chr [1:1] "Content page 1_pdf3 Content page 2_pdf3"
 .
 .
 .
```

I tried this `map` function

```
> pdfs = pdf_filenames %>% 
        map(pdf_text) %>%
        map(c(1,2))
```

but that returned an empty list.

```
> pdfs
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
.
.
.
```

Appreciate your help very much! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a lambda expression (`~`) to apply the `pdf_text` on the elements individually and then `paste/str_c` the first two elements (based on the expected output)

```
library(dplyr)
library(pdftools)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
pdf_filenames %>% 
        map( ~ {
           x1 <- pdf_text(.x)
           c(str_c(head(x1, 2), collapse = " "), tail(x1, -2) )
        })
```